# Laravel 5 Query relationship not working

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I have two tables as follows:

1). myurls

```
    id    domain      
----------------------
    1     google.com
    2     test.com
    3     example.com  etc
```

2). links

```
     id  myurls_id   end_date              created_at
---------------------------------------------------
     1     2       2016-11-30 00:00:00   2016-11-30 00:00:00
     2     2       2016-12-01 00:00:00   2016-11-30 00:00:00
     3     2       NULL                  2016-11-30 00:00:00
     4     2       2017-01-01 00:00:00   2016-12-01 00:00:00
     5     3       2016-11-24 00:00:00   2016-12-01 00:00:00
     6     3       2016-10-01 00:00:00   2016-12-01 00:00:00
```

etc...
they have one to many relationship with myurls_id as you can see

in this example for myurls_id (2) we have 4 record :
2 record where end_date is expired
1 record where end_date is NULL
1 record where end_date is NOT expired

I want to write a laravel relationship query where it will get me expired URLs that means query the results where if you find at least one NULL or one not expired not listed we only want to list if all the 4 record are expired. how can I do that

here is what I have but its not working:

```
$expired_domains = Myurls::with(['links' => function ($query) {
         $query->whereNotNull('end_date')
                ->where('end_date','<',Carbon::now())
                ->where('created_at', '<', Carbon::now())
                ->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')
                ->first();

}])->get();
```

this is showing me that test.com & example.com both are EXPIRED which is wrong but its not because there is at least one end_date "NULL" or not expired record in links table, it suppose to only give me example.com Expired because all its link end_date expired

How to do this I appreciate your help

Comment: any help with this?

Comment: Anyone with ideas can anyone provide me with sql query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you are intending, as I understand, can be done as

```
//In your MyUrls model define two relationships
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class MyUrls extends Model
{
    protected $table="myurls";

    protected $fillable = ['domain'];

    public function links()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Link::class, 'myurls_id');
    }

    public function active_links()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Link::class, 'myurls_id')
                    ->whereApproved(1)
                    ->where('end_date', '>', Carbon::now());
    }

    public function null_links()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Link::class, 'myurls_id')
                    ->whereApproved(1)
                    ->whereNull('end_date');
    }

    public function unapproved_active_links()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Link::class, 'myurls_id')
                    ->whereApproved(0)
                    ->where('end_date', '>', Carbon::now());
    }

    public function unapproved_null_links()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Link::class, 'myurls_id')
                    ->whereApproved(0)
                    ->whereNull('end_date');
    }
}
```

You can apply whatever ordering you need within the relationship for eg `return $this->hasMany('active_links', 'myurls_id')->where('end_date', '>', Carbon::now())->orderBy('end_date', 'dsc');`.

If you are using default `timestamps()` in your migrations, then you probably do not need to check `where('created_at', '<', Carbon::now());`.

Then in your controller (or wherever else) you can get the domains data as

```
$allDomains = MyUrls::all();  //list of all domains

//All domains which have links but do not have active_links are expired.
//Domains without any links will not be listed here.
$expiredDomains = MyUrls::has('links')
                         ->doesntHave('active_links')
                         ->doesntHave('null_links')
                         ->doesntHave('unapproved_active_links')
                         ->doesntHave('unapproved_null_links')
                         ->get();

//All domains which have active_links are active.
//Domains without any links will not be listed here.
$activeDomains = MyUrls::has('active_links')->get();
```

Then in your view you can use

```
    <h4>All Domains</h4>
    <ul>
        @foreach($allDomains as $domain)
            <li>{{$domain->domain}}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
    <hr />
    <h4>Expired Domains</h4>
    <ul>
        @foreach($expiredDomains as $domain)
            <li>{{$domain->domain .' is an expired domain '}}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
    <hr />
    <h4>Active Domains</h4>
    <ul>
        @foreach($activeDomains as $domain)
            <li>{{$domain->domain .' has an end date of '.$domain->active_links[0]->end_date}}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
```

Hope this is what you are intending and it helps get you started.

Comment: I am geting an error on this line MyUrls::whereHas('links')  saying it excepts 2 parameters??

Comment: I have edited the answer, in this case since we are not filtering the results of `whereHas` and `whereDoesntHave` we can simply use `has` and `doesntHave` instead. For advanced filtering we can use advanced where clauses, refer Laravel Documentation - https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations

Comment: for expired domain only it will return example.com I don't think ur example with return only example،com it's returning both domains example,com and test،،com bc the issue here there might be a duplicate end date that has Null and or not expired

Comment: I have tested the code, it is returning only example.com for expired domains and test.com for active domains.

Comment: I am testing it on Laravel 5.3, don't know exactly what changed from 5.2 to 5.3 in respect of the code in the answer. Here's the screen shot of the above code when I tested - http://imgur.com/a/YBzKP. You can have a look at the upgrade section of Laravel Documentation to find out - https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade

Comment: ill check because I don't see in laravel 5.2 doesnthave that's why maybe it's not working is there away around that ?

Comment: If I want also to add where status is Approved , do I added it to the Model ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130182/discussion-between-donkarnash-and-user3150060).

Comment: Sir Downvoter, please explain the reason for downvote in comment for me to understand and not repeat such mistake in future. Thanks.

Comment: Hi ya can you add approve status and I will chat with you

Comment: I need to add a condition bc it's not working when there is one pending that has end date null

Comment: I guess that we are already checking with `unapproved_null_links` so shouldn't be a problem